# Can't manage roles in DNN (get 404 error)

Tags: dotnetnuke

I have a DNN site up an running and everything seems to work EXCEPT for when I attempt to manage roles for a user or manage roles.  When I click on the link I get a 404 error.

I am using an older version of DNN (based on .net 1.1) and I am putting it on IIS7.

This is a forklift move from one server to another so upgrading to a newer DNN is only a last resort option at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was something wrong with the URL rewriting.  In the HostSetting I set the Use Friendly URLS to No and the problem went away.